# How to produce additive Sin wave?

Tags: plotting, animation

I am trying to produce a similar animation like the following, only with two peaks moving towards each other instead of parallel. How do I do that?

[image]

My objective: 
Two peaks approaching each other
[image]
When they pass through each other, they have constructive interference.
[image]

My code:

```
Animate[Plot[
   If[Pi <= x + t <= 2 Pi || 3 Pi <= x + t <= 4 Pi, -Sin[x + t], 0], 
   {x, 0, 4 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {t, 2 Pi, -2 Pi, -0.05}]
```

Comment: Perhaps a little clarification? Do you mean two single half-sine moving from opposite sides and passing through each other unaffected, or with constructive interference?

Comment: Oh yes, I mean they pass through each other with constructive interference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Animate[
 Plot[UnitBox[(x - Pi/2. - t)/Pi] Sin[x - t] + 
   UnitBox[(x - 3.5 Pi + t)/Pi] Sin[x + Pi + t], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {-2, 2}}],
 {t, 0, 10}
 ]
```

[image]